# Delta and Wye configuration

Tags: motor, transformer

The problem:Complete the transformer wiring diagrams according to the Delta primary and Wye secondary configuration.  The secondary will be configured for High voltage.  Connect all loads as needed.

This is my solution:
[image]

The problem: Complete the transformer wiring diagrams according to the Wye primary and Wye secondary configuration.  The secondary will be configured for Low voltage.  Connect all loads as needed.

My solution:

[image]

I put the red and blue connections. I did not get any information on the voltage or kW. The question is: Did i wire the diagram correctly given the problem?

Comment: If i connected the diagram correctly

Comment: have you addressed each of the configuration requirements?

Comment: Primary looks good.  Secondary side, I'm not sure on transformer connections, but line connections are fine. I'd connect single phase loads to bottom phase (not top) to make loads more balanced (without knowing kW).

Comment: I edited the post, hopefully it will make more sense.

Comment: For the first diagram, I think the secondaries are wired for low voltage - for high voltage you need to connect the half-windings in series.